# staticmethod from function object. Why don't I need to staticmethod it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let us, counterfactually, assume I had a good reason for wanting to make builtin `print` a static method of some class.

My, apparently wrong, gut feeling was that I need to declare it static doing something like

```
class sm:
    p = staticmethod(print)
```

as opposed to

```
class no_sm:
    p = print
```

But it seems both work just fine.

```
a = sm()
b = no_sm()

a.p("hello")
b.p("hello")
```

prints

```
hello
hello
```

Why does it just work and is there any difference between the two?

Related: [Why use staticmethod instead of no decorator at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15317478/7207392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for ~most normal functions, they go through a descriptor protocol (`__get__`) and so they need special decorating when attached to classes in the way you're doing.

take for example:

```
def f():
    print('hi')

class C:
    f = f

class D:
    f = staticmethod(f)
```

in this case `C().f()` errors:

```
>>> C().f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

that's because it goes through:

```
>>> C.f.__get__(C())()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

but you'll notice, that `print` has no such attribute `__get__`:

```
>>> hasattr(print, '__get__')
```

it even has a different type!

```
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
```

so the answer is: `print` (along with other C functions) without special treatment do not participate in the method descriptor protocol so they act as normal callable objects without attachment of `self`

Comment: So, essentially I picked a bad test case. I did not know that builtins are so fundamentally different from pure Python functions. Another skeleton in Python's cupboard... Anyway, very useful to know. Thanks!